# How to call function in certain time interval

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to run a certain API function, in a certain time period once the access token is granted, and check the status and inform the user if there any changes.

So far i did it by clicking a button on popup window of the firefox addon and calling the functions background js files, so i can receive the info from the API and notify the user. But i need to automate this process in background js files.

Are there any firefox inbuild JS API or any other way to achieve this auto API request calling from addon background files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is, the `setInterval()` function.

```
let inter = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('HI!');
}, 1000);
```

To stop the timer, just call: `clearInterval(inter);`

More info about `setInterval()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Comment: i will give a try ;)

Comment: its working. :D are there any official way of doing this? i mean is this how other extenstion developers call the API and check any changes?

Comment: If you need of a so continuous check I recommend to you make the inverse way, the server saying that something changed, to do it, take a look on https://socket.io/